# Eclipse Juno/Kepler crashes

Tags: eclipse

I've got problem with Eclipse.
It crashes time by time (4-5 times a day), without any errors! (CPU usage is also normal), but I can't do anything - click or write in Eclipse, or close this application. Only kill "javaw" process in process manager helps.
After restart, my workspace is corrupted and I have to configure some things again (custom perspectives and install other versions of JDK). It is very problematic.

Any ideas?
Some info I have found, refer to older versions of eclipse.

I've tried EE and standard version, Kepler and Juno, on Windows, without any plugins.

Comment: Don't you have an plug-in that connects to a remote source? My Eclipse sometimes starts about 5 minutes or it seems to not responding, but it gets back working after this long time. I believe, that IVY plug-in does such bad job in my Eclipse.

Comment: have you tried reinstalling java? Eclipse is also rather bulky and takes a lot of memory, maybe you have a bad RAM stick. Do you ever get random crashes when running other applications?

Comment: Try taking a look at the contents of your logfile in /workspace/.metadata/.log

Comment: and a crash log, that should appear in Eclipse home directory and has name like hs_err_pid<pid>.log

Comment: Same here. If the crash log has "webkitWebViewRegisterForIconNotification", it's likely related to [this bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=400626).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found solution: there isn't proper java version installed. My Eclipse was 64bit version, but there was only java 32-bit installed, so I install full pack: jre7 32bit, jre7 64bit, jre6 32bit and jre6 64bit. 
Now everything works properly.

Answer (score 21):

I add following line to eclipse.ini

```
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.DefaultType=mozilla
```

and this line to config.ini

`org.eclipse.swt.browser.DefaultType=mozilla`

and my problem solved.

Comment: Worked for me, thanks!
For those who wonders where are those files :
 - [eclipse_path]/eclipse.ini
 - [eclipse_path]/configuration/config.ini

Comment: Had the same issue with Eclipse Luna. This fixed it as well.

Answer (score 3):

1) If different Eclipse versions have the same problem, than it is problem of your PC configuration and not of Eclipse. Have you tried to do the same on other PC?

2) For your PC the problem may be old version of Java, e.g. Java 7 less than update 12.

3) Maybe current user setting were corrupted, try to login as different user.

4) Review `/workspace/.metadata/.log` for analysis.

Answer (score 1):

Even I was facing the same problem. In my case I had installed jdk6, 7, and 8 at the same time. My eclipse was using jdk6, My Android studio was using jdk8.

Solution : Uninstall all jdk,jre version and keep only one jdk-jre. I kept jdk6/jre6, this solved the issue